# Skew one side of image

Tags: image, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3

I'm going to be doing a project on a Raspberry Pi where I display an image through a projector.  The image is a rectangle that exactly twice as long as it is wide.  Since I'm displaying via the projector, that means the side furthest from the project will end up being narrower than the closer side, so I need to expand that side of the image.

Can someone point me in the right direction of how I'd implement that please?  I don't even know what the right terminology is to good it and look into the math I'd need to do.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to use (say) command-line tools to distort your image, or that you want to process it using code you write? A good tool for distorting images in all sorts of clever ways is `convert`, which is part of the ImageMagick package.

Comment: I’d process it via code.

Comment: I have 4 points on the projected surface that make a rectangle, so my thought was an initial calibration image would just draw a rectangle, and then adjust the image until each corner touched those 4 points, and then I'd know my exact 'offsets' that I'd have to account for.

Comment: @KevinBoone Would you be able to tell me how to do it via command line?  I could always start with that, and eventually figure out the code later.

Comment: I still don't really understand the problem -- are you trying to distort a rectangle into a trapezium? Or skew it into a parallelogram? Where is the projector with respect to the screen?

Comment: @KevinBoone Imagine the "screen" is just the floor.  The projector is on the ceiling pointed down at a 45-ish degree angle.  So when I display a rectangle, where the longer side goes 'away' from the projector, it's going to look like a trapezium.  Imagine looking at a picture of a road that goes way into the distance, where the far side is narrower than the close side.  So to make it look like a rectangle on the floor, I have to expand the far side of the image before I project it so it ends up looking rectangular.  Make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're asking for is called "keystone correction," I believe. Many video projectors can do this automatically, so it's worth checking before writing a pile of code :)

Here's how to do this using the ImageMagick `convert` utility. You need to know the size of the image to start with. For the sake of discussion, let's assume it's 889 x 746. Also, let's assume we want the image to be "thinner" at the bottom than the top, by 60 pixels, and that the "thinning" is symmetrical about the vertical centre-line.

So let's call the top-left pixel (1,1), the top-right (889,1), the bottom left (1,746) and the bottom-right (889,746). The top-left and top-right pixels stay where they are; the bottom-left "moves" from (1,746) to (61,746). The bottom-right moves to (829,746), because 889-60 is 829 -- this is a move to the left.

The `convert -distort perspective` command requires the coordinates of four pixels, their pre-move and post-move values. It then calculates how to move all the other pixels, such that straight lines in the original remain straight. So, taking the calculated values above, we need:

```
convert in.png -virtual-pixel transparent -distort perspective \
   '1,1  1,1         \ 
    889,1 889,1      \
    1,746 60,746     \
    889,746 829,746' \ 
    out.png
```

Of course, the spacing isn't essential: it's just to show how the numbers line up with the calculated values above.

Naturally, you'll need to adjust the numbers to suit your image size, and the degree of correction you need. ImageMagick is avilable for Raspberry Pi, and it's easy enough to embed a call to `convert` in application code.

Comment: You're welcome. If my answer was helpful, do feel free to click the little up arrow, so other people know ;)

Comment: So this is really two steps the way I'm seeing it.  Since I want the top wider than the original image, I first have to resize the width of the original image to be wider than it was, and then use the distort you showed me to make the *bottom* narrower, right?

Comment: I guess so, but I think that `convert` will work with pixel locations outside the original image if necessary.